# Authenticated fetch request is only working half of the time

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, fetch

I am attempting to make an authenticated fetch request from a react component to my django api backend, however it is only working half of the time (usually right after I login and authenticate the user). The other half of the time I get a 401 (Unauthorized): "Unauthorized: /api/payments/charge/"

My redux dev tools clearly shows that the token is present:
[token present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UfYC.png)

Can anyone help me determine why this is?

FRONTEND:
My react component's submit method:

```
async submit(ev) {
    // User clicked submit

    let {stripeToken} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: this.state.cardholderName})
    let amount = this.state.amount

    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    })
    let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payments/charge/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: 'JWT ' + this.props.token

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({stripeToken, amount})
    })

    if (response.ok) console.log("Purchase Complete!")
    if (response.ok) this.setState({complete: true, isLoading: false});

  }
```

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    token: state.token
  }
}

export default injectStripe(connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(CheckoutForm)))
```

BACKEND:
api/views.py

```
class ChargeAndCreateCustomerAPIView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # Check if user is authenticated
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:

            print('USER IS AUTHENTICATED')

            user = self.request.user

            if user.profile.stripe_customer_id != '':
                print('CUSTOMER ID IS: ' + str(user.profile.stripe_customer_id))
            else:
                print('CUSTOMER HAS NO ID')
                customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                    source=request.data['token']['id'],
                    email='paying.user@example.com',
                )
                user.profile.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
                user.save()

                print('created new customer id: ')
                print(user.profile.stripe_customer_id)

            amount = int(request.data['amount'])*100
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=amount,
                currency='usd',
                description='A Django charge',
                customer=user.profile.stripe_customer_id
            )

        return Response(status=200)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' : (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    )
}
```

WHEN IT FAILS:
console error: 
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoM5t.png)

django server error in the terminal:
[django terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoI6v.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used JWT with [Roll](https://github.com/pyrates/roll) and was facing a similar issue.

It might be that your JWT secret is resetting each time your server restarts.
In which case the token you send cannot be validated anymore as the secret is different and you need to regenerate a token.

However, to fix this issue you can hard code your secret for development in a settings or somewhere else.